# I am getting run time error 462

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

HI,

I have the following piece of code in Access.

```
Dim objSht As excel.Worksheet
Dim objexcel As New excel.Application
Dim wbexcel As excel.Workbook
Dim wbExists As Boolean
Dim objRange As excel.Range
Dim isFileAlreadyPresent As Boolean

Set objexcel = CreateObject("excel.Application")

Set wbexcel = objexcel.Workbooks.Open(file_name)
Set objSht = wbexcel.Worksheets(table_name)
isFileAlreadyPresent = True

objSht.Activate
objSht.Range(Range_para).Select
Charts.Add
ActiveChart.chartType = xlColumnClustered
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets(table_name).Range(Range_para), _
                            PlotBy:= xlColumns
ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet
ActiveChart.HasLegend = False

With ActiveChart
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Characters.text = CHart_title
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = False
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = False
End With

If isFileAlreadyPresent = True Then
    wbexcel.Save
Else
    wbexcel.SaveAs (file_name)
End If
objexcel.Visible = True
wbexcel.Close
```

I am having two problems. Every second time I run the code I get an run time error 462 (The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable ) at line Charts.add.

I know that I am not using the objexcel property correctly but I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Also after the code is run, even though excel closes. The process runs in the background and this interferes with the next run of the code. How do I close excel and get rid of it from task manager processes also?

Comment: Try to remove everything from your code that is not required to reproduce the issue. This will make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: It seems problematic to me that you have both Dim objexcel As New excel.Application and Set objexcel = CreateObject("excel.Application"). If you use the latter, you don't need the New keyword in your variable declaration.

Comment: I agree with Peter's comment. It may be worth your while to re-post  your code (you can edit your question) so that it at least compiles.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to create the chart object like this, since your using late binding it won't know what "Charts" is unless you call it from the parent object.

```
objexcel.Charts.Add
```

Error 462 usually means something isn't qualified right, even though the message is sort of cryptic.

Comment: Just tried it with your code (had to fake out some variables though).
Once the Charts.Add thing is fixed, it seems to work multiple times. It'll just ask you to replace text.xls.  It's probable that when you ran into the Charts.Add, it never got a chance to finish.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a quick fix trying setting everything you declare/use to nothing at the end of your code to ensure that nothing is left open or active.

```
Set objSht = Nothing
```

Let me know if that fixes the problem

Comment: It is good practice to explicitly destroy objects once you're done with them. However I believe, for the most part, VBA has its own object disposal service for this and it has never failed me yet. (At least that is what Microsoft says...Dunno - that would be a good question - I believe one of the creators of SO worked on the Excel VBA team back in its day)

Answer (score 0):

As you your question

> How do I close excel and get rid of it
>   from task manager processes also?

You should be able to use the `Application.Quit` command at the end of your code as long as you aren't running the sub from another application other than Excel. Or, you should be able to do an `objexcel.Quit` command. Another alternative method is to delegate this to a shell command: `Shell "taskkill /f /im excel.exe"`.

I hope this helps. Did you get a working piece of code yet?

Comment: Uh, try reading the first sentence of the question: "I have the following piece of code in Access."